# Uniting TCP and UDP in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, tcp, udp

So ideally, I am looking for a way to unite TCP and UDP on the server and manage both these connections under individual client threads. Currently, I am wondering if it is possible to accept a TCP connection and set up UDP communication from that.

Here is my ideal setup:

1. Client connects on TCP to server via TCPClient.connect()
2. Server accepts TCP connection via TCPListener
3. when server accepts TCP connection, it also gets the IPEndpoint from the TCP connection

and uses that to begin UDP communcation with:

```
serverUDPSocket.BeginReceiveFrom (byteData, 0, 1024, 
               SocketFlags.None, ref (Endpoint)ThatIPEndpointThatIJustMentioned, 
               new AsyncCallback(client.receiveUDP), 
               (Endpoint)ThatIPEndpointThatIJustMentioned);
```

^so this is where I am running into a little bit of a theoretical issue.  From my understanding, the endpoints for TCP and UDP would be formatted differently. How can I resolve this issue?  I would like to avoid having the client connect to UDP on a separate thread and then uniting these threads under a single managing class.

EDIT:

Here is the code that I am trying to implement:

```
//Listening for TCP
TcpClient newclient = listenTCP.AcceptTcpClient(); //Accept the client
Client clientr = new Client(newclient); //Create a new Client class to manage the connection
clientr.actionThread = new Thread(clientr.action); //This thread manages the data flow from the client via the TCP stream
clientr.actionThread.Start(clientr);
EndPoint endPoint = newclient.Client.RemoteEndPoint; //so this is the sketchy part. I am trying to get the endpoint from the TCP connection to set up a UDP "connection". I am unsure about the compatibility as UDP and TCP sockets are different.
UDPSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(new byte[1024],0,1024, SocketFlags.None,ref endPoint, new AsyncCallback(clientr.receiveUDP), null); //the AsyncCallBack is like the manager thread for UDP (same as in TCP)
clients.Add(clientr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a lack of understanding of UDP on my part from the code level.

I ended up setting up the other method I described where it would accept initial UDP packets individually and then direct the communication (EndPoint + Message) towards a managing client class by comparing IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in creating two listeners in one application, even if they use different protocol. I suppose you are not asking if you can do it on the same port (there is no point to do it anyway).

However listener is consuming thread so it need different thread if there is gui or some process to do in application (for example calculations meanwhile).

If you want to do everything in one thread you must first receive message from first listener, then setup second one. There is no possibility to setup 2 listeners in one thread at the same time because if you setup first listener it will consome whole thread waiting for message.

Comment: I think my confusion lies within the flexibility of IPEndpoint. I am pretty sure you can set up TCP and UDP on the same port, and I would like to keep them on the same port for the sake of consistency. The TCP listener is consuming a thread, and I would like it to accept a connection and use the information from that connection to set up another one on UDP (and I use the word "connection" here very sparingly).